# Can't display on LCD with Atmega 328

Tags: atmega, lcd

I tried to display hello world on a 20x4 LCD using Atmega328. But I failed to display any character on the screen. I'm not sure where the problem is, either the initialization or the timing order. I am using PortB as data port and PortD0 as RS, PortD1 as RW, and PortD2 as EN.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <string.h>

#define dataport PORTB
#define commport PORTD

#define rs  PD0
#define wr  PD1
#define en  PD2

int LCD_Init(void);
int LCD_SendData(unsigned char *);
int wrcomm(void);
int wrdata(void);

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0xFF;    //set portD 4,5,6 as output pins
    _delay_ms(500);

    LCD_Init();
    while (1)
    {
        LCD_SendData("hello");
        dataport = 0xC0;
        wrcomm();
        LCD_SendData("world");
    }

    //while(1);

    return 1;
}

int LCD_Init(void)
{

    //Function set
    dataport = 0x38;    //0b00111000, DL = "Low", 8-bit mode; N = "high", 2-line display; F=0, 5x8 display
    wrcomm(); 
    _delay_us(50);

    //clear LCD screen
    dataport = 0x01;    //clear screen
    wrcomm();
    _delay_ms(2);

    //display on/off control
    dataport = 0x0e;    //0b00001110, D=1, display is turned on; C=1, cursor is turned on; B=0, blink is off
    wrcomm();

    //cursor at line 1
    dataport = 0x80;
    wrcomm();
    _delay_us(50);

    //entry mode set
    dataport = 0x06;
    _delay_us(50);

    //cursor or display shift
    dataport = 0x1C;    //0b00011100, S/C=1, R/L=1, shift all the display to the right, cursor moves according to the display
    wrcomm();
    _delay_us(50);

    return 1;

}

int LCD_SendData(unsigned char *s)
{
    unsigned char *j = s;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(j); i++)
    {
        dataport = j[i];
        wrdata();
    }
    return 1;
}
int wrcomm(void)
{
    commport &= ~(1 << rs);     //selecting command register
    commport &= ~(1 << wr);     //selecting write mode
    _delay_us(200);
    commport |= 1 << en;        //EN = 1 
    _delay_ms(1);
    commport &= ~(1 << en);     //EN = 0
    _delay_ms(1);
    return 1;
}
int wrdata(void)
{
    commport |= 1 << rs;        //selecting data register
    commport &= ~(1 << wr);     //selecting write mode
    _delay_us(200);
    commport |= 1 << en;        //EN = 1
    _delay_ms(1);
    commport &= ~(1 << en);     //EN = 0
    _delay_ms(1);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code yet but have a question: what voltage is your ATmega328 running at?  What voltage is your LCD rated to work at?  The reason I ask is that many LCD displays do not work at 3.3V.

Comment: Do you see anything at the LCD (e.g. 8 black rectangles)?

Comment: @DwayneReid, I'm using 5VDC for both the microcontroller and the LCD. I tried to separate the supply voltage of the LCD and the  MCU, but still didn't work.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, I cannot see anything on the LCD, no rectangles, no characters. And I tried different LCDs, it was the same thing.

Comment: When an HD44780 LCD powers up, it shows 8 dark rectangles on the first 8 positions. So you must be doing something wrong with the hardware. Which contrast voltage do you use?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, I'm using a 10k potentiometer as the contrast voltage.

Comment: A potentiometer is not a voltage! Which voltage is on the Vee pin? 0V is the best bet for a first try, but some displays require a negative voltage.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, the potentiometer is wired between 5V and GND, so there is a positive input voltage at Vee. I am not sure if Vee ought to be 0 or negative.

Comment: OK, so you wired the potmeter that way, but which way did you turn it? Turn it towards GND for a start.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen. Now I have dark rectangles as you said, it seems that I messed with the value of the potentiometer. But I still cannot display strings on it, would you help me with the code?

Comment: No, I am not gona debug yet another HD44780 initialization. Check for yourself, did you follow the mandatory initialization *exactly* as it is stated in the datasheet? It is there for a reason.

Comment: I looked at your code and you might not be using correctly the ""int" and "init." More comments as to what each line is doing would help in debugging the code.